# NotSerializableException when pressing home button

Tags: android

I have an `Activity` in which I have a private class Data.
In the `onSaveInstanceState` method, I try to save this an instance of `Data`.
This is my whole Activity:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
        outState.putSerializable("TEST", new Data());
    }

    private class Data implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -4312723541994925110L;

    }
}
```

Now when I change the orientation of the device, the `Data` object is saved and read as it should. However, when I press the home button, the app crashes with the following in the logcat:

> 05-10 20:05:51.895: E/AndroidRuntime(30317): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   05-10 20:05:51.895: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing
>   serializable object (name = com.rigidbits.test.TestActivity$Data)
>   05-10 20:05:51.895: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):  at
>   android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1176) 05-10
>   20:05:51.895: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):    at
>   android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1130) 05-10 20:05:51.895:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(30317):  at
>   android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:488) 05-10
>   20:05:51.895: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):    at
>   android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1552) 05-10 20:05:51.895:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(30317):  at
>   android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:502) 05-10 20:05:51.895:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(30317):  at
>   android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityPaused(ActivityManagerNative.java:1615)
>   05-10 20:05:51.895: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
>   05-10 20:05:51.895: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:117) 05-10
>   20:05:51.895: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:938)
>   05-10 20:05:51.895: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 05-10
>   20:05:51.895: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130) 05-10 20:05:51.895:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(30317):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683) 05-10
>   20:05:51.895: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 05-10
>   20:05:51.895: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 05-10 20:05:51.895:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(30317):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:862)
>   05-10 20:05:51.895: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620) 05-10
>   20:05:51.895: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 05-10 20:05:51.895:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(30317): Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException:
>   com.rigidbits.test.TestActivity 05-10 20:05:51.895:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(30317):  at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1535)
>   05-10 20:05:51.895: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):  at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1847)
>   05-10 20:05:51.895: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):  at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1689)
>   05-10 20:05:51.895: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):  at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1653)
>   05-10 20:05:51.895: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):  at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:1143)
>   05-10 20:05:51.895: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):  at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:413)
>   05-10 20:05:51.895: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):  at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1241)
>   05-10 20:05:51.895: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):  at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1575)
>   05-10 20:05:51.895: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):  at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1847)
>   05-10 20:05:51.895: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):  at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1689)
>   05-10 20:05:51.895: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):  at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1653)
>   05-10 20:05:51.895: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):  at
>   android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1171) 05-10
>   20:05:51.895: E/AndroidRuntime(30317):    ... 16 more

When I comment the line in the `onSaveInstanceState` method so the `Data` object is *not* saved, the app disappears correctly.

Any help with this?

Comment: just for interest make your UID `1L` instead of a negative number

Comment: I've tried it, but no luck. The UID is a value generated by Eclipse.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Ok I believe the problem is that you are using a **private inner class**.

Therefore it has **access to the methods and fields of your outer class** i.e. your activity.

Because your activity isn't serializble (*and so it shouldn't be*), your getting your exception.

> An instance of InnerClass can exist only within an instance of OuterClass and has direct access to the methods and fields of its enclosing instance.

[image]

There are two solutions.

- Make your inner class static
- Move your inner class to be a class of its own and declare it public

These solutions both make your `Data` class a class in its own right and then it doesn't need your activity instance to exist

Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Comment: Wow, very clear answer, and it works! Thanks a lot! I have made it a static class, because I've got a fair lot of Activities that need a Data class, and it has unique fields for each of them.