# AsyncTask with REST API

Tags: android, rest, android-activity, android-asynctask, networkonmainthread

I have an Android app that uses a REST API to populate a list.

I am trying to get the API using an AsyncTask, but I am having trouble understanding how it works. I am creating the API object in the background to avoid a NetworkOnMainThreadError, but this leads to my createItems( ) method being invoked on a null object.

How can I create the API object in the background and still be able to use it during the OnCreate? Thanks!

Here is a segment of my OnCreate( ) method:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer);

        createLists();
        populateNameLists();
        new GetAPITask().execute();
        createItems();

(...)
    }
```

And here is the method causing the error (createItems( )):

```
public void createItems() {
        testString = api.testSession();
        itemString = api.getItems(...);
(...)
    }
```

Here is the AsyncTask:

```
private class GetAPITask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            api = new API(getString(R.string.dev_id), getString(R.string.auth_key));

            return "API Created";
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The point of using an AsyncTask is to get data in background and once you get the data you populate your views with it. You only run your methods to populate the views once the data is ready to be used, which should be handled inside `onPostExecute`. You should do it like this:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        createItems();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your ASyncTask has a reference to the outer class

change the signature to

```
 private static class GetAPITask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
```

This will stop you being able to access the code and variables inside the class.

**which is how you get to access `api` outside of the ASyncTask - causing your confusion**

More explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10540669/413127

---

That then means you cannot access the `api` variable outside of the ASyncTask (which is correct). You'll then have to move your code into the background thread, and decide what you what your ASyncTask to return. At the moment it returns a `String`;

You can access that String with a callback:

```
private static class GetAPITask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        interface Callback {
            void onComplete(String text);
        }

        private final API api;
        private final Callback callback;

        GetAPITask(API api, Callback callback) {
            this.api = api;
            this.callback = callback;
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            return "API Created";
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            callback.onComplete(result);
        }
    }
```

And then use it like so:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer);

    //createLists();
    //populateNameLists();
    API api = new API(getString(R.string.dev_id), getString(R.string.auth_key));
    new GetAPITask(api, new GetAPITask.Callback() {
          @Override
          public void onSuccess(String result) {
                 Log.d("TUT", "My asynctask returned: " + result);
          }
    }).execute();
    //createItems();

    (...)
}
```

As you can see, now it is cleaned up, your ASyncTask isn't doing anything but returning the String inside the `doInBackground()` method. You need to move the code you want to execute inside here! 
(i.e. move `createItems` inside `doInBackground()`)

---

Something like:

```
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String testString = api.testSession();
            String itemString = api.getItems(...);
            (...)               

            return testString;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            callback.onComplete(result);
        }
```

If you want to return multiple Strings from your ASyncTask , you will have to create a data class and return that.